# array output from Python ctypes?

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I need to call a C function from Python, using ctypes and to have that function provide one or more arrays back to Python. The arrays will always be of simple types like long, bool, double.

I would very much prefer if the arrays could be dynamically sized. I will know the needed before each call, but different call should use different sizes.

I suppose I should allocate the arrays in Python and let the C code overwrite the contents, so that Python can eventually de-allocate the memory it allocated.

I control both the Python and the C code.

I have this now which does not work:

C:

```
FOO_API long Foo(long* batch, long bufferSize)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++)
    {
        batch[i] = i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Python:

```
print "start test"
FooFunction = Bar.LoadedDll.Foo
longPtrType = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_long)
FooFunction.argtypes = [longPtrType, ctypes.c_long]
FooFunction.restype = ctypes.c_long

arrayType = ctypes.c_long * 7
pyArray = [1] * 7
print pyArray
errorCode = FooFunction(arrayType(*pyArray), 7)
print pyArray
print "test finished"
```

Produces:

```
start test
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
test finished
```

Should Produce:

```
start test
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
test finished
```

Why does this not work? Or do I need to do this in a different way?

Comment: Maybe try Cython + numpy, see here http://kbarbary.github.io/blog/cython-and-multiple-numpy-dtypes/

Comment: @mirosval: No thanks. The solution is complicated enough as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C array is built using the python list; both are different objects. And the code is print the python list, which is not affected by `Foo` call.

You need to build the C array, pass it, then use it after the call:

```
arrayType = ctypes.c_long * 7
array = arrayType(*[1] * 7)
print list(array)
errorCode = FooFunction(array, len(array))
print list(array)
```

Comment: Thanks. I arrived at another option, which I have posted, but I am marking your answer as the solution since you got there first and since your answer changes my original code less than my own. I wonder if one is preferable over the other for whatever reason, though? Performance matters.

Comment: P.S. i am new to StackOverflow. Is there something I have to do to get email notifications?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to falsetru for the extremely quick answer. I did no notice it right away and in the mean time I arrived at this, which also seems to work. I wonder if one is preferable to the other?

```
print "start test"
FooFunction = GpGlobals.LoadedDll.Foo
longArrayType = ctypes.c_long * (7)
FooFunction.argtypes = [longArrayType, ctypes.c_long]
FooFunction.restype = ctypes.c_long

pyArray = longArrayType()
for l in pyArray:
    print l        
errorCode = FooFunction(pyArray, 7)
for l in pyArray:
    print l
print "test finished"
```

I did not initially think that this would work with dynamically sized arrays, but all that I had to do was redefine the argtypes before each call.

Comment: You were better off using `ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_long)` in `argtypes` since it accepts any `long *` pointer, including `long` arrays of any size since they're passed as a pointer. As to iterating the result instead of creating a list, that's preferred if you don't actually need to create a list. There's no need to duplicate the data in two objects.